# Replace a word that is not on a string

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I'm trying to replace a word in a file whenever it appears except when it is contained in a string:

So I should replace `this` in

```
The test in this line consists in ...
```

But should not match in :

```
The test "in this line" consist in ...
```

This is what I'm trying:

```
 line.replaceAll( "\\s+this\\s+", " that ")
```

But it fails with this scenario so I tried using:

```
 line.replaceAll( "[^\"]\\s+this\\s+", " that ")
```

But doesn't work either.

Comment: So strings in this scenario contain no escape characters?

Comment: That's right I just should ignore anything inside a string...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work (in so far as I understand your requirements from the examples provided):

```
 (?!.*\s+this\s+.*\")\s+this\s+
```

http://rubular.com/r/jZvR4XEbRf

You may need to adjust the escaping for java.

This is a bit better actually:

```
 (?!\".*\s+this\s+)(?!\s+this\s+.*\")\s+this\s+
```

Comment: I believe it's called a negative look around, excludes strings that match that criteria.

Comment: http://rubular.com/r/Bz9lEasQWT  shows it working, can you provide an example?  I never tried 2 negative look arounds in java...

Comment: The exact line where the first passes but the later fails: `out.println("adding this to other")`

Comment: This only works because every match is on a separate line in your test.  Add the `m` modifier (so the `.` can match newlines) and you get no matches.  There is a way to do this with a lookahead (see my demo), but I don't recommend it.

Comment: +1 because this is about as good as you're going to get with regex I think. But it still fails e.g. - here is this test "in" a line - regex just isn't a reliable way of marking when the quotes start and finish.

Answer (score 2):

The only reliable way to do this is to search for EITHER a complete, quoted sequence OR the search term.  You do this with one regex, and after each match you determine which one you matched.  If it's the search term, you replace it; otherwise you leave it alone.

That means you can't use `replaceAll()`.  Instead you have to use the `appendReplacement()` and `appendTail()` methods like `replaceAll()` itself does.  Here's an example:

```
String s = "Replace this example. Don't replace \"this example.\" Replace this example.";
System.out.println(s);

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"[^\"]*\"|(\\bexample\\b)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

while (m.find())
{
  if (m.start(1) != -1)
  {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, "REPLACE");
  }
}
m.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

output:

```
Replace this example. Don't replace "this example." Replace this example.
Replace this REPLACE. Don't replace "this example." Replace this REPLACE.
```

**[See demo online](http://ideone.com/J4PPq)**

I'm assuming every quotation mark is significant and they can't be escaped--in other words, that you're working with prose, not source code.  Escaped quotes can be dealt with, but it greatly complicates the regex.

If you really must use `replaceAll()`, there *is* a trick where you use a lookahead to assert that the match is followed by an even number of quotes.  But it's really ugly, and for large texts you might find it prohibitively expensive, performance-wise.